# How to execute all proto chain of a method in a class?

Tags: javascript, oop, prototype

I think the code will be a best explanation of my issue:

```
function getMyConstructor(){
   ...
}

const MyConstructor = getMyConstructor({
  x: 0,
  getX: function(){ return this.x; }
},{
  x: 1,
  getX: function(){ return this.__getX() + '  first'; }
},{
  x: 2,
  getX: function(){ return this.__getX() + '  second'; }
},{
  x: 3,
  getX: function(){ return this.__getX() + '  third'; }
});

const myInstance = new MyConstructor;

console.log( myInstance.getX() ) // 3 first second third
```

Does someone know how to implement the `__getX` method?

**UPDATE:**
I've made the code but I think that it's not so pretty

```
function getMyConstructor() {
    return Array.prototype.reduce.call(arguments, (proto, obj, index, args) => {
        function C() {
        }

        C.prototype = Object.create(proto);

        for (let p in obj) {
            if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
                continue;
            }

            C.prototype[p] = obj[p];
            if (index > 0 && typeof obj[p] === 'function') {
                C.prototype['__' + p] = setBaseMethod(p, proto);
            }
        }

        return index === args.length - 1 ? C : C.prototype;
    });

    /**
     * @param {string} method
     * @param {Object} proto
     * @returns Function
     */
    function setBaseMethod(method, proto) {
        let obj = {};
        obj[method] = proto[method];
        obj['__' + method] = proto['__' + method];

        return function () {
            let context = {};
            for (let p in proto) {
                if (this[p] && typeof this[p] !== 'function') {
                    Object.defineProperty(context, p, {
                        get: () => this[p],
                        set: value => this[p] = value,
                        enumerable: true,
                        configurable: true
                    });
                }
            }

            return Object.assign({}, context, obj)[method]();
        }
    }
}
```

I hope the code suggest how to resolve the problem

Comment: What is your [actual problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)? I have no idea what you want to do, what this has to do with prototypes, or where there is a chain in your example.

Comment: Look, `myInstence` looks like `{x:3,getX:function(){...},__getX:function(){...}, __proto__: { x:2, getX:function(){...}, __getX: function(){...}, __proto_:{...} }}` I need to know how to implement `__getX` that the method will call `getX` method of his parent but context must be own...

Comment: You probably shouldn't be doing this, but see my answer for how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun, since you asked for a prototype chain:

```
function chainPrototypes(...objs) {
  return objs.reduce((p, o) => Object.setPrototypeOf(o, p));
}

const myInstance = chainPrototypes({
  x: 0,
  getX() { return this.x; }
}, {
  x: 1,
  getX() { return super.getX() + '  first'; }
}, {
  x: 2,
  getX() { return super.getX() + '  second'; }
}, {
  x: 3,
  getX() { return super.getX() + '  third'; }
});

console.log(myInstance.getX()); // 3  first  second  third
```

Just use method definitions with the [`super` keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/super).